# Error for caffe-windows

Tags: c++, windows, caffe

When I download the windows version for caffe, when I try to run examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh, the following error appears

```
 $ sh examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh
 Creating lmdb...
 C:/Users/zhang/caffe-windows/Build/x64/Release/convert_mnist_data.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory}
```

I am pretty sure all the project in caff.sln build successfully, and I download the third party in the right folder, can anyone help me fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

try right cilck convert_minist_data project and set it to start project and then recompile it .